# Up-to date and future proof way of detecting iOS in PHP (or Server side)

Tags: javascript, php, ios

I know similar question have been asked quite often but many of them are outdated, and things changed quite a lot, therefore I'm asking the community again (in October 2017) how can we detect if the user is using and iOS device or not, and I highlight iOS, I don't care about any other platforms.

**Reason why I need detection**

I'm displaying pictures on my website and the user can click on some of them to download the full high-res picture. On the server side I'm using X-SENDFILE to push the file to the user, which works nicely on everything except iOS which lacks the download function, therefore in iOS case I need to modify the headers and present the image as an image rather than an attachment so the user can tap on it and save it to the gallery manually.

I can use user-agent sniffing (like I did in the past):

```
$iPod    = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$iPhone  = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$iPad    = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
```

but this won't cut it for in-app browsers (like Facebook, Twitter, etc), yes you can keep adding rules to the list, but it will be a constant catch-up game and how do you actually really keep a track of all the possible 3rd party apps which changes the agent string. I don't want to keep going back and updating my page, it's a bit ridiculous in my opinion.

So my question is whether there is any better way to detect iOS?

**Preferred solutions in order**

1. Detect from Server side
2. Detect from client side (javascript)
3. Use an external library (similar to https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect, maybe even payed, which can be linked to the page rather than built in)

I'm not too keen about the 3rd option, because that again will rely on the library being constantly updated, what if the development stops, it's another thing which I must keep track of and forgetting to do so can lead to functionality being broken in future.

Comment: Did you try seeing what in-app browsers return for JavaScript's `navigator.platform`?

Comment: navigator platform same as useragent can be modified and again, with the multitude of inapp browsers it's getting harder to be sure of the device... which again leads back that you have to play a catch-up game.

Comment: Everything can be modified eventually, the question is what is the most reliable method.

Comment: Agree on that part. Ideally but I'm affraid that will not possible, the most reliable should be a feature detection which can return true/false if the device has an underlying filesystem or not. (in a nutshell that is the root cause of the problem)

Comment: did you try this one ? http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Comment: Regex updated 2014 :) at least that's what the website reads....

Answer (score 0):

The current mechanism which is used to detect user agent is what you have mentioned. Comparatively, In App browser traffic is lesser than the app/desktop traffic. So the solution you should be looking for is how to identify in app browser traffic. Well, lets break it down and understand what in app browsers are.

As per [this link](http://www.stateofdigital.com/facebook-browser-biggest-browser-ignore/)

> “In-app browsers” are not actual browsers, but a webview window running off your device’s core browser. Safari passes the “(in-app)” string into the browser name, but others don’t.  As far as Google Analytics is concerned, a webview window based on Chrome is simply Chrome.

Its basically a web view window running off your device's core browser, which in case of iOS is Safari and in case of Android, its Chrome.

Now to identify this on server side, we can do this:

```
//For iOS

if ((strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Mobile/') !== false) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Safari/') == false) {
    echo 'WebView';
} else{
    echo 'Not WebView';
}

//For Android

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "com.company.app") {
    echo 'WebView';
} else{
    echo 'Not WebView';
}
```

Well as we know headers can be faked, so this is not the nicest solution.

For identifying webviews on client side, use this:

```
var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
safari = /safari/.test( userAgent ),
ios = /iphone|ipod|ipad/.test( userAgent );

if( ios ) {
    if ( safari ) {
        //browser
    } else if ( !safari ) {
        //webview
    };
} else {
    //not iOS
};
```

The third solution is using mobile detect which i recommend because it does the same thing and offers a bunch of more features which could be handy.

Comment: The only real question is how accurate and safe is to assume that all iOS apps will contain the iphone/ipad/ipod string? I don't care too much if the user uses a WebView or not all I care is if it's an iOS os, and how safe it is to assume that other browsers won't inject this words for what not reasons (See IE 11 changing the UserAgent string)

Comment: There would always be browsers or apps who wouldn't follow the standard practice for UserAgent string. We cant have a 100% fool proof system. But what I can surely tell is if the iOS app is browsing your web page using a web view, It will always have the iOS user agent string. In case of ios web browsers, we cant be sure of all of them, so we target majority. I dont see any other way of detecting ios traffic

Comment: Some browsers even allow users to edit the User Agent string via browser preferences (!). Fun, but trouble for situations like this. Totally agree with this answer and comments: we can't have a 100% fool-proof, or future-proof system. There are too many fools, and too much future ahead of us.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to detect the user agents that don't support the `X-SENDFILE` header (there may very well be more than just iOS that don't support it), I would suggest just using the `Content-Disposition: Attachment` header, which should work for all clients.

The reason for using the `X-SENDFILE` header would be to avoid having to load the file into memory before pushing it down the wire, however, you can mitigate that by streaming the file instead of loading it into memory in its entirety.

```php
<?php
function streamfile($filepath, $buffer_size) {
    $buffer = '';
    $handle = fopen($filepath, 'rb');

    if ($handle === false) {
        return false;
    }

    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fread($handle, $buffer_size);
        echo $buffer;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }

    return fclose($handle);
}

$filepath = 'path/to/your/file';
$filename = 'Name of My File';
$mimetype = 'mime/type';

header('Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename="'. $filename .'"');
header('Content-Type: '.$mimetype );
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filepath));

streamfile($filepath, 4096);
?>
```

If the files are located on a remote server, you can alter the function to use `fsockopen` instead of `fopen`.